# Why doesn't my program print out the values I want?

Tags: c, if-statement

I've been scratching my head over this one for a while now.

I'm trying to write a program that randomly generates the score in 6 hockey games and assigns the results to certain values. However, the points awarded to the winning team (3 for a victory, and 1 for a tie) doesn't seem to be stored correctly in the post in the post I'm trying to add them to (serie[i].poang), since the last part of the program just prints out the scores of each team as "0" when I run the program. My best guess is that something is off with the if-else statements that assign the score, but I can't find anything myself.

The variables are written in Swedish, so go ahead and ask if anything about that is unclear. Thanks on beforehand!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ESC 27


struct lag {   //Struct team, char name, int goals made, int goals let in, int points
    char namn[20];
    int gjorda;
    int inslappta;
    int poang;
};

int main(void) {
    struct lag temp, serie[] = {   //The names of several swedish hockey teams
            {"Bryn\204s",        0, 0, 0},
            {"Djurg\206rden",    0, 0, 0},
            {"Fr\224lunda",      0, 0, 0},
            {"F\204rjestad",     0, 0, 0},
            {"HV 71     ",       0, 0, 0},
            {"Link\224ping",     0, 0, 0},
            {"Lule\206     ",    0, 0, 0},
            {"MODO    ",         0, 0, 0},
            {"R\224gle     ",    0, 0, 0},
            {"Skellefte\206",    0, 0, 0},
            {"S\224dert\204lje", 0, 0, 0},
            {"Timr\206     ",    0, 0, 0}
    };
    int i, j, hemma, borta;


    srand((unsigned) time(NULL));


    do {
        system("cls");
        for (i = 0; i <= 10; i += 2) {
            hemma = rand() % 8;  //Both teams are assigned random goals
            borta = rand() % 8;
            serie[i].gjorda = serie[i].gjorda + hemma;
            serie[i].inslappta = serie[i].inslappta + borta;
            serie[i + 1].gjorda = serie[i + 1].gjorda + borta;
            serie[i + 1].inslappta = serie[i + 1].inslappta + hemma;

            printf("%s - %s \t \t \t \t %d - %d \n", serie[i].namn, serie[i + 1].namn, hemma,
                   borta);  //The results of each game is printed out
        }

        if (hemma > borta)               //Score assignment, this is where I think the problem is
            serie[i].poang = serie[i].poang + 3;

        else if (hemma == borta) {
            serie[i].poang = serie[i].poang + 1;
            serie[i + 1].poang = serie[i + 1].poang + 1;
        } else if (hemma < borta)
            serie[i + 1].poang = serie[i + 1].poang + 3;


        for (i = 0; i < 11; i++)
            for (j = i + 1; j < 12; j++)
                if (serie[j].poang < serie[i].poang) {
                    temp.poang = serie[i].poang;
                    serie[i].poang = serie[j].poang;
                    serie[j].poang = temp.poang;

                    temp.gjorda = serie[i].gjorda;
                    serie[i].gjorda = serie[j].gjorda;
                    serie[j].gjorda = temp.gjorda;

                    temp.inslappta = serie[i].inslappta;
                    serie[i].inslappta = serie[j].inslappta;
                    serie[j].inslappta = temp.inslappta;

                    strcpy(temp.namn, serie[i].namn);
                    strcpy(serie[i].namn, serie[j].namn);
                    strcpy(serie[j].namn, temp.namn);
                }

        for (i = 0; i < 11; i++)
            for (j = i + 1; j < 12; j++)
                if (serie[j].poang == serie[i].poang)
                    if ((serie[j].gjorda - serie[j].inslappta) < (serie[i].gjorda - serie[i].inslappta)) {
                        temp.poang = serie[i].poang;
                        serie[i].poang = serie[j].poang;
                        serie[j].poang = temp.poang;

                        temp.gjorda = serie[i].gjorda;
                        serie[i].gjorda = serie[j].gjorda;
                        serie[j].gjorda = temp.gjorda;

                        temp.inslappta = serie[i].inslappta;
                        serie[i].inslappta = serie[j].inslappta;
                        serie[j].inslappta = temp.inslappta;

                        strcpy(temp.namn, serie[i].namn);
                        strcpy(serie[i].namn, serie[j].namn);
                        strcpy(serie[j].namn, temp.namn);
                    }

        for (i = 0; i <= 11; i++) {
            printf(" %s \t \t %d - %d \t \t %d \n", serie[i].namn, serie[i].gjorda, serie[i].inslappta, serie[i].poang);
        }
    } while (_getch() != ESC);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should do some debugging, and report back with what you find.

Comment: @tambre - huh?  why?

Comment: at `if .. else if .. else if` : `i` is invalid subscript because this is outside for-loop.

Comment: @tambre It makes it a bit harder to get help on here, I know. I'm doing my best to explain the parts in Swedish

Comment: @BLUEPIXY ```i``` is declared outside of the for-loop. Confused here.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Oh shoot you're right! if...else if....else if should be inside the for-loop, right?

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve] anyway, so might as well translate your symbols as part of the transition.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY That solved it, thanks everyone!

Comment: @tambre True.  In addition, if you cannot debug, it's also a bad idea to write code in English :(

Comment: Du borde använda engelska ord istället för svenska. Du märker väl själv att det är jobbigt att inte kunna använda åäö

Comment: @ErikW Förvisso, men den här uppgiften bestod av ett påbörjat programskal som vi skulle bygga på utan att ändra. Kan vara en idé att i framtiden börja göra program med engelska namn i sig dock